# What interesting information can be deduced from knowledge of how deep a geodesic ventures into the cusp

Tags: nt.number-theory, ds.dynamical-systems, ergodic-theory, hyperbolic-geometry

First of all I have to apologise as I am not a geometer and my knowledge of geometry is poor. Let $M$ be the modular surface and $\gamma$ to denote a geodesic in $M$. In the the following paper by Gadre, Maher and Tiozzo 
[Word length statistics for Teichmüller geodesics and singularity of harmonic measure](http://www.maths.gla.ac.uk/~vgadre/papers/word_teich.pdf)
(see also Gadre,[Partial sums of excursions along random geodesics and volume asypmtotics...](http://www.maths.gla.ac.uk/~vgadre/papers/Exc-sums.pdf)), the authors consider a quantity $E(\gamma,T)$ which they call the total excursion up to time $T$ of the geodesic $\gamma$. To my possibly wrong understanding, it is roughly the total distance a geodesic traveled into the cusp up to time $T$. These two papers are concerned with studying the asymptotics of this quantity for typical (chosen uniformly w.r.t. some natural measures). My questions are as follows:

(1) What kind of important geometric/ number theoretic are known to be affected by this quantity? What is the importance of knowing its asymptotics.

(2) One can define similarly a quantity $E(\gamma,-T)$ to be the same thing but for the geodesic running in inverse time (similar to the double boundary). I found out that there exists a measurable function (can be chosen to be Cadlag) $\kappa(\gamma,T): T_1(M)\times (0,\infty)\to \{\pm1\}$ so that for a typical geodesic w.r.t. the Liouville measure 
$$\frac{E(\gamma,\kappa(\gamma,T)\cdot T)}{T\log T}\to 1\ \text{as}\ T\to\infty,$$
and 
$$\frac{E(\gamma,-\kappa(\gamma,T)\cdot T)}{T\log T}\to \infty\ \text{as}\ T\to\infty.$$
The speed of convergence of the second term to infinity is governed by some extreme value statistics. Does a statement of this type have any meaning in hyperbolic geometry. There is an equivalent theorem for the natural extension of the Farey map--- sums of continued fraction digits.